# Windows fatal access violation within pytest

Tags: python, windows, pytest

I am trying to connect to informix DB using python through (jaydebeapi,ifxjdbc3.5.jar) but i am getting windows fatal error access violation. When I run following code without pytest plugin then its work properly.

Versions detail are as follows:

- Python(3.11)
- JayDeBeApi(1.2.3)
- JPype1(1.4.1)
- pytest(7.4.0)

My code is:

```
import pytest
import os
import jaydebeapi
from Database_Testing.Tests.ConfigDB import \*
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def DatabaseConfigurations():
current_dir = os.getcwd()
\# Specify the relative path to file
relative_path = 'ifxjdbc3.5.jar'
# Construct the absolute path by joining the current directory and the relative path
absolute_path = os.path.join(current_dir, relative_path)

conn = jaydebeapi.connect(
"com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver",
"Connection string"
"8859-1,819;IFX_USE_STRENC=true;LOBCACHE=-1;",
["Username", "Password"],
jars=[absolute_path]
)
yield conn
conn.close()`
```

The error:

```
    Error:

    test_db_connection.py::test_db_conn Windows fatal exception: access violation Current thread                0x00005028 (most recent call first): 
Thread details..........

ERROR
test setup failed

??? E Exception: Java Exception

org.jpype.JPypeContext.java:-1: Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def DatabaseConfigurations():
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    # Specify the relative path to your file
    relative_path = 'ifxjdbc3.5.jar'

    # Construct the absolute path by joining the current directory and the relative path
    absolute_path = os.path.join(current_dir, relative_path)
conn = jaydebeapi.connect(
        "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver",
        "Connection string"
        "8859-1,819;IFX_USE_STRENC=true;LOBCACHE=-1;",
        ["Username", "Password"],
        jars=[absolute_path]
    )
```